# Correct kmod-megasr driver to install CentOS 7 on Intel Embedded RAID Technology II?

Tags: drivers, centos, raid, software-raid, intel-rst

I am trying to install CentOS 7 on a server using RAID 5 on Intel Embedded RAID Technology II. I did need to install a special hardware key to unlock the RAID 5 feature.

I have succcessfully installed CentOS on a similar system in RAID 0 without loading any special drivers. I have successfully installed and initialized a RAID 5 array using the Intel RAID Controller II. However, when I try to install in RAID 5 mode, the CentOS 7 installer cannot see my RAIDed hard drive. My BIOS does show the RAID array as a boot option.

For budget reasons, I would like to get this working for my school. I have two USB ports, no CD-ROM drive, and space for only three physical hard drives in this system. I am using the full DVD iso on one USB drive, and have the megasr image on a second USB drive. I used the following command to make the driver USB:

```
sudo dd if=ESRT2_Linux_v.15.04.2013.1016/DUDs/megasr-15.04.2013.1016-1-rhel64-ga-x86_64.img of=/dev/sdb
```

As you can see, I am using the most recent driver I could find, for RHEL 6.4. I can load that driver prior to install using the following command, apparently successfully:

```
linux dd modprobe.blacklist=ahci
```

However, when I get to the GUI install screen, the only HDD that appears is one of my 8 GB thumb drives plugged in to the server. The same thing happens if I just use the same command without "dd" thereby skipping the loading of drivers.

Is there a megasr (or kmod-megasr) driver for CentOS 7? What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hey, if you're going to vote my question down, it would be constructive to tell me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grabbing the newest one from here. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=ESRT2 or more specifically https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24636/ESRT2-RAID-driver-for-Linux-

There is an rpm version as well as the .img DUD file try both. I've had trouble installing for different kernel versions but give that a try.

Hope that helps!